# Cannot connect to Node.js application on shared server

Tags: node.js

I have setup a node.js application and it's running on port 4999, but when I browse to the url `www.website.com:4999` I get a `This site can’t be reached` error in Chrome and `Secure Connection Failed` in Firefox

The is the code in SSH used to start the node app

```
[~/public_html/customer_portal]# gulp serv:prod
[13:48:50] Using gulpfile ~/public_html/customer_portal/gulpfile.js
[13:48:50] Starting 'ConcatScripts'...
[13:48:50] Starting 'ConcatCss'...
[13:48:50] Starting 'CopyAssets'...
[13:48:50] Finished 'ConcatCss' after 553 ms
[13:48:50] Starting 'UglyCss'...
[13:48:50] Finished 'CopyAssets' after 855 ms
[13:48:50] Finished 'UglyCss' after 322 ms
[13:48:50] Finished 'ConcatScripts' after 925 ms
[13:48:50] Starting 'UglyScripts'...
[13:49:08] Finished 'UglyScripts' after 18 s
[13:49:08] Starting 'Inject:PROD'...
[13:49:08] gulp-inject 1 files into index.build.ejs.
[13:49:08] gulp-inject 1 files into index.build.ejs.
[13:49:08] Finished 'Inject:PROD' after 218 ms
[13:49:08] Starting 'build:prod'...
[13:49:08] Finished 'build:prod' after 61 μs
[13:49:08] Starting 'serv:prod'...
[13:49:08] Finished 'serv:prod' after 48 ms
livereload[tiny-lr] listening on 35729 ...
Mon, 25 Jul 2016 03:49:09 GMT express-session deprecated undefined     saveUninitialized option; provide saveUninitialized option at app.js:58:13
XXX service has been started at port: 4999 !!!
```

Comment: Are you using ExpressJS? Will be good if you can show us the server's source code.

Comment: @SamuelToh I wouldn't have a clue, I'm not a node developer, I installed application and then got the `XXX service has been started at port: 4999 !!!` message. Which part of the server code do you want?

Comment: I see. Probably update the question with the code around the place that starts the server? Hope you understand that without the code it's impossible for us to debug with just the error message.

Comment: @SamuelToh no problems, I have added the code

Comment: that is not the source code. :( It is the standard output written by the gulp binary. Am expecting the code from those .js files. Essentially the entry point for the program.

Comment: recommend googling for some nodejs tutorial and see which one best fits what you're trying to achieve and start there instead. I think even if the guys solve your current issue, there might be more to uncover.

Comment: @SamuelToh it won't let me add the source code, says I need to add more details. I tried searching for tutorials, didn't find anything, I'm also not interested in learning node. I can get the app working on my localhost, but just not on the website

Comment: Set your port to equal process.ENV.PORT

Comment: @milky_jay since you are not keen in web development then I won't explain too deeply also. Your issue is with `gulp serve`. Basically you are trying to host your web application through a development server. You should be hosting your web application through an actual web server like `nginx`.

Comment: @SamuelToh Who said I'm not keen on web development, I specified node. The guy who build the app said to use “gulp serv:dev” for development and “gulp serv:prod” for the live site. The site is on a shared hosting account and we were trying to see if we could get it working, it seems to be running, but I just cannot connect to it.

Comment: @milky_jay apologise if that have caused you any anger. You might want to check whether the server which you are hosting the app has port `4999` forwarded? That is, it actually exposes port 4999 to the outside world. Otherwise external people will not be able to connect into the application.

Comment: @SamuelToh Thanks for you help, apparently that's the issue, the host doesn't allow it

Comment: @milky_jay If you have no control over the host easiest way would be to host it on port 80. Look for the value `4999` in the gulp file and change it to 80 and see it works for you. Do you mind if I just post up a quick answer for this issue. This is so that it can have a closure

Comment: @milky_jay I have sum up our conversation and proposed a solution to the problem. If I have helped you in anyway - will appreciate if you can click on the tick beside my answer to mark this as answered. For other questions please feel free to raise it and give me a shout. Will try to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just compiling the solution we derived from the comment in OP's post.

So OP had tested his nodeJS application locally and now he is wanting to expose it to the world wide web. While OP did not post content of his `gulpFile` but I am guessing that he is trying to use a development server spin up by `gulp` to serve his web page. Not impossible, however certainly not recommended.

A better replacement would be to use a real web server like `nginx`.

**See:**

https://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html

Back to the original problem. The real reason why OP is getting hit by the error `This site can’t be reached` was probably because his server did not have the required port forwarded, in this case port `4999`. To workaround this temporarily would be to update the Gulp file to host the application on port `80` instead.

However I am still dubious about the error message because I would have thought OP should see something like `connection refused`. Anyway, this is not important.

To sum up, OP should consider fixing his problem by;

1. install a real web server on his machine
2. place the application onto the installed web server